# RBAC not working for grails default action calling

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0, spring-security-rest

I have a restController with a rest end point as list

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

class MyRestController {

    @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
    def list() {
        render(['status': 200, 'message': 'Access granted for list'] as JSON)
    }

}
```

I applied RBAC on list for Role 'ROLE_ADMIN' but when I am accessing this controller without specifying action name(default URI for a controller), it's giving me response even when I am not logged in.

When I am calling API with URL http://localhost:8080/myRest/list, it's redirecting me to login page; which is the expected behaviour.
But when I am hitting default url for controller in my browser, I am getting response.

API Calling URL:
http://localhost:8080/myRest

Response:
[API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zan46.png)

```
{"status": 200,"message": "Access granted for list"}
```

Accessing http://localhost:8080/myRest should redirect me to login page or should give 404 but definitely should not respond me with list restAPI response.

I am using Grails 2.5.4.
Please suggest if I am doing something wrong or how can I fix this vulnerability.